# Using Google Maps in a car with a Hotspot and a cell phone with no sim card

Tags: mobile-data, wifi-hotspot, google-maps-navigation

I have a  AT&T Samsung Galaxy 7. 
I have another AT&T phone with no sim card. 
I have a verizon hotspot and will be purchasing an AT&T hotspot as i am converting to almost full time RV'ing.

Is it possible to use google maps, Waze, or any other driving app like that with my no-sim card phone through one of my hotspots as i drive the country ?

Answer (score 0):

Given that I've sat in a moving bus only using WiFi an can see the blue dot in Google Maps move down the street, it should work.

You may have location problems if there isn't any GPS signal and you are in an area where there is little geolocated WiFi hotspots/signals.

Comment: Are you saying there a difference between geolocated WiFi hotspots/signals and cellphone geolocated signals ??
If it works as well with a hotspot as a direct cellphone with a sim card, then that's all i'm looking for...

Comment: Personally I would keep a phone with valid sim in reserve, but my point is that in urban areas GPS signals may not be the best so the location service drops back to WiFi hotspot triangulation, if you are using a phone, cell tower location will be used for triangulation as well. Replace urban with other rural area with poor GPS signal same fallbacks to cell tower/wifi hotspots occurs. I don't believe AGPS is passed along via hotspot.